# ¿Se pueden pedir opiniones en una pregunta/discusión?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, cierre-de-preguntas

Estaba leyendo la documentación del sitio para realizar preguntas, pero no encontré(o puede que no la haya visto) una referencia acerca de las preguntas que buscan la opinión de expertos que frecuentan el sitio, por ejemplo, ¿Qué prácticas son las mejores al realizar un página web/app/proyecto?

¿Este tipo de preguntas son aceptadas por el sitio?

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que no hay dogmas del tipo "buenas prácticas" sólo hay estándares que van variando según el contexto. Algo que sirve en situación A puede generar problemas en cascada en situación B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ese tipo de pregunta se les llaman **principalmente basadas en opiniones** las cuales no se permiten en el sitio principal, de hecho, existe un motivo de cierre estándar para ellas.

Más información en [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) y [¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Cabe hacer notar que podrías lograr la participación de los expertos del sitio planteando una pregunta específica e interesante y tendrás aún mayor probabilidades si la pregunta está bien formada. Además, cuando ya tengas algo de reputación podrás ofrecer recompensas para destacar tu pregunta durante algunos días.

Answer (score 7):

Respuesta corta:

No. Las preguntas pidiendo opiniones no son aceptadas (fuentes: [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) y [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

---

Respuesta larga (**ésta es mi opinión personal, no una regla o la línea de SOes**):

Depende mucho del alcance de la pregunta y de cómo se escriba. Por ejemplo, la cuestión que se plantea como ejemplo:

> ¿Qué prácticas son las mejores al realizar un página web/app/proyecto?

Aparte de que pueda ser basada en opiniones, es increíblemente amplia. Se podrían escribir, ya no un libro, sino series de libros enteros sobre ese tema. En ese caso, la publicación seguro acabará cerrada ya sea como "se basa principalmente en opiniones" o como "demasiado amplia".

Pero... si el tema fuera más concreto, entraríamos en una zona más gris y se podría debatir la cabida en el sitio. Y aquí es donde entra en juego cómo se escribe la pregunta.

Por ejemplo, si en lugar de cómo realizar una página web en general, preguntaras sobre algo (mucho) más específico como poner texto en imágenes:

> ¿Qué prácticas son las mejores al añadir texto sobre imágenes?

Entonces la pregunta deja de ser amplia, aunque el título sugiere subjetividad. Se está pidiendo los "mejores" de algo, y muchos usuarios lo van a considerar como basado en opiniones y votarán por cerrar. En ese caso en concreto, deberías plantearte usar términos establecidos que, aunque puedan ser subjetivos, han perdido un poco esa connotación:

> ¿Buenas prácticas al añadir texto sobre imágenes?

O incluso mejor, centrarte en el problema en sí:

> ¿Cómo hacer que el texto sea legible al ponerlo sobre una imagen?

Estas tres últimas preguntas son idénticas: el título cambia pero el cuerpo de la pregunta va a ser parecido o casi igual en los tres casos... sin embargo una va a acabar cerrada como subjetiva, otra puede que también, y la tercera en cambio seguramente sea bien recibida.

Con esto no digo que las preguntas subjetivas sean permitidas si se escriben bien. Si escribes como un Nobel de Literatura pidiendo recomendaciones de libros/plugins/programas/etc. tu publicación acabará cerrada, sí o sí.

A lo que me refiero es que muchas veces la subjetividad de la pregunta viene porque la pregunta en sí es muy amplia y deja mucho espacio para variables y opiniones. Escribir más detalles y centrarse en algo concreto elimina ese vacío. La pregunta quizás siga siendo algo subjetiva, pero dentro de un contexto mucho más definido.

---

...Y con esto creo que he escrito en chorrocientos párrafos lo mismo que Rubén ha escrito en tres :P

Comment: No, no has escrito lo mismo para nada, es muy interesante eso que dices y los ejemplos que has puesto ya que es lo que puede marcar la diferencia entre una pregunta cerrada y posiblemente con varios negativos y otra que reciba algunas buenas respuestas y dé unos cuantos puntos de reputación, todo eso preguntando prácticamente lo mismo. Está claro que el ejemplo del OP tiene poca solución al abarcar toda una disciplina entera pero en temas un poco más concretos la redacción es la clave.

Comment: Feature request: Marcar respuestas como duplicadas :P. Fuera de bromas, si bien coincidimos en la idea central me parecen útiles los ejemplos que has incluido.